# Getting connect ETIMEDOUT in reaching AWS mysql when load on the RDS

Tags: amazon-rds

We are running the AWS "db.m5.2xlarge" and are having some weird connection issue in our application when the database is at his peak / what is not really clear to us is that we are merely reaching 200 concurrent connection but the max of connection is supposed to be at 2590 (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';).
The CPU (40%) and memory usage are
Is there a specific parameter other than this one that somehow limits the number of request per host?
Can we trust this parameter as being the total number of concurrent connection available?
Thanks

I am expecting to be able to use the full number of connection available as describe per max_connections